# Initialize variable with value stored in an external file

Tags: java

I have an `Email` class which is abstract. It has several children: `AuthenticationEmail`, `MarketingEmail`, etc. I want to initialize value of a field (which is final static) with a string stored in an external file.

At first I though I could use Spring's `@Value` but it turned out that the class needs to be a component. Then I tried the following code (static initialization and etc.):

```
public abstract class UserAccountAuthenticationEmail extends Email implements Serializable {    
    @Value("${email.address.from.authentication}")
    private final static String SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS;

    static {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "config.properties";
        InputStream inputStream;
        if (inputStream != null) {
            prop.load(inputStream);
            inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getSender() {
        return SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work either, as `getClass` is a non-static method and cannot be instantiated inside the static block.

How can I initialize the value of this variable from a file? and preferably only one time. Is there any standard method to do that? something like `@Value`, instead of manually reading from IO?

Comment: If you use spring XML configuration, then you can use `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to set the value. No need to mark it as component, just need to use `abstract="true"`

Comment: I'm trying to find an example in Spring boot, but all of the classes I could find were annotated with either `Bean`, `Component` or `Configuration`. Can you point me to an example?

Comment: You could try the static method `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`

Comment: Why do you need the SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS to be static final ?

Comment: @FabienMIFSUD as long as it read from file only once, and not for every instance of the class, I'm fine.

Comment: So you can keep your @Value, remove setter if you have one and remove static final (if you use spring, the default bean scope is Singleton).

Comment: It's not a bean. This class is not annotated at all.

Comment: @FabienMIFSUD I tried it and I still can not use `@Value`

Comment: Does your bean is "springed" ? Annoted with @Component or declared in an xml context file ?

Comment: If I make it a component, I should `@Autowired` it, which doesn't make sense since I want to instantiate this class every time a request comes to the rest controller.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it can help you. A static final variable can't be changed after the first initialization.

```
public  class UserAccountAuthenticationEmail  implements Serializable {

private final static String SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS =getVal();
public static String getVal() {

    try {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "C:\\SMS\\config.properties";
        InputStream inputStream;
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(propFileName);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            prop.load(inputStream);
           return prop.getProperty("email");
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it this way:

```
private final static String DEFAULT_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS;

static {
    String value = "";
    try {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "application.properties";
        InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            prop.load(inputStream);
           value = prop.getProperty("email.authentication.sender");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DEFAULT_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS = value;
}

public String getSender() {
    return DEFAULT_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
}
```